# Decimal point can not enter in Silverlight's TextBox

Tags: c#, silverlight

I’m using Silverlight 5.

I’m having problem to enter decimal point in my TextBox. Every time I entered a decimal point, the cursor will always return back to the beginning of value entered in the TextBox and the decimal point will be removed.

Strange thing is that this problem only occurs when I deploy my application on IIS and running it from internet browser. The problem was **NOT** there when I run it from Visual Studio 2010 in debug mode.

Bellow is my XAML code for the TextBox:

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedModel.MyHight, 
Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
Helper:TextBoxFilter.Filter="PositiveDecimal"/>
```

The Helper Class TextBoxFilter actually doing the PositiveDecimal filtering. Bellow are the classes (These are not my codes. Got it somewhere in the internet):

**TextBoxFilterType.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace NumericUpdateSourceProblem
{
    public enum TextBoxFilterType
    {
        None,
        PositiveInteger,
        Integer,
        PositiveDecimal,
        Decimal,
        Alpha,
    }
}
```

**TextBoxFilter.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace NumericUpdateSourceProblem
{
    public class TextBoxFilter
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Filter Attached Dependency Property
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty FilterProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Filter", typeof(TextBoxFilterType), typeof(TextBoxFilter),
                                            new PropertyMetadata(OnFilterChanged));

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the Filter property. 
        /// </summary>
        public static TextBoxFilterType GetFilter(DependencyObject d)
        {
            return (TextBoxFilterType)d.GetValue(FilterProperty);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the Filter property.  
        /// </summary>
        public static void SetFilter(DependencyObject d, TextBoxFilterType value)
        {
            d.SetValue(FilterProperty, value);
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Handles changes to the Filter property.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="d">DependencyObject</param>
        /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
        private static void OnFilterChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox textBox = d as TextBox;
            if (TextBoxFilterType.None != (TextBoxFilterType)e.OldValue)
            {
                textBox.KeyDown -= new KeyEventHandler(textBox_KeyDown);
            }
            if (TextBoxFilterType.None != (TextBoxFilterType)e.NewValue)
            {
                textBox.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(textBox_KeyDown);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles the KeyDown event of the textBox control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
        /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
        private static void textBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            // bypass other keys!
            if (IsValidOtherKey(e.Key))
            {
                return;
            }
            //
            TextBoxFilterType filterType = GetFilter((DependencyObject)sender);
            TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
            if (null == textBox)
            {
                textBox = e.OriginalSource as TextBox;
            }
            //
            switch (filterType)
            {
                case TextBoxFilterType.PositiveInteger:
                    e.Handled = !IsValidIntegerKey(textBox, e.Key, e.PlatformKeyCode, false);
                    break;
                case TextBoxFilterType.Integer:
                    e.Handled = !IsValidIntegerKey(textBox, e.Key, e.PlatformKeyCode, true);
                    break;
                ase TextBoxFilterType.PositiveDecimal:
                    e.Handled = !IsValidDecmialKey(textBox, e.Key, e.PlatformKeyCode, false);
                    break;
                case TextBoxFilterType.Decimal:
                    e.Handled = !IsValidDecmialKey(textBox, e.Key, e.PlatformKeyCode, true);
                    break;
                case TextBoxFilterType.Alpha:
                    e.Handled = !IsValidAlphaKey(e.Key);
                    break;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether the specified key is valid other key.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key">The key.</param>
        /// <returns>
        ///     <c>true</c> if [is valid other key] [the specified key]; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
        /// </returns>
        private static bool IsValidOtherKey(Key key)
        {
            // allow control keys
            if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) != 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            // allow
            // Back, Tab, Enter, Shift, Ctrl, Alt, CapsLock, Escape, PageUp, PageDown
            // End, Home, Left, Up, Right, Down, Insert, Delete 
            // except for space!
            // allow all Fx keys
            if (
                (key < Key.D0 && key != Key.Space)
                || (key > Key.Z && key < Key.NumPad0))
            {
                return true;
            }
            // we need to examine all others!
            return false;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether the specified key is valid integer key for the specified text box.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="textBox">The text box.</param>
        /// <param name="key">The key.</param>
        /// <param name="platformKeyCode">The platform key code.</param>
        /// <param name="negativeAllowed">if set to <c>true</c> [negative allowed].</param>
        /// <returns>
        ///     <c>true</c> if the specified key is valid integer key for the specified text box; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
        /// </returns>
        private static bool IsValidIntegerKey(TextBox textBox, Key key, int platformKeyCode, bool negativeAllowed)
        {
            if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Shift) != 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            if (Key.D0 <= key && key <= Key.D9)
            {
                return true;
            }
            if (Key.NumPad0 <= key && key <= Key.NumPad9)
            {
                return true;
            }
            if (negativeAllowed && (key == Key.Subtract || (key == Key.Unknown && platformKeyCode == 189)))
            {
                return 0 == textBox.Text.Length;
            }
            //
            return false;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether the specified key is valid decmial key for the specified text box.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="textBox">The text box.</param>
        /// <param name="key">The key.</param>
        /// <param name="platformKeyCode">The platform key code.</param>
        /// <param name="negativeAllowed">if set to <c>true</c> [negative allowed].</param>
        /// <returns>
        ///     <c>true</c> if the specified key is valid decmial key for the specified text box; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
        /// </returns>
        private static bool IsValidDecmialKey(TextBox textBox, Key key, int platformKeyCode, bool negativeAllowed)
        {
            if (IsValidIntegerKey(textBox, key, platformKeyCode, negativeAllowed))
            {
                return true;
            }
            if (key == Key.Decimal || (key == Key.Unknown && platformKeyCode == 190))
            {
                return !textBox.Text.Contains(".");
            }
            return false;
            //
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether the specified key is valid alpha key.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key">The key.</param>
        /// <returns>
        ///     <c>true</c> if the specified key is valid alpha key for the specified text box; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
        /// </returns>
        private static bool IsValidAlphaKey(Key key)
        {
            if (Key.A <= key && key <= Key.Z)
            {
                return true;
            }
            //
            return false;
            //
        }
    }
}
```

I don’t understand why it behave differently in development environment (debug) and implementation environment (deploy on IIS version 5.1).

p.s: If I remove **UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged** in Text properties, it will works fine. But I need that property to update source without losing focus.

[Download Source Code here](http://sdrv.ms/15LZsUe)

Thank You

Comment: In the `IsValidDecmialKey` function try to replace `return !textBox.Text.Contains(".");` by `return true;`.

Comment: @vorrtex Still the same problem.....

Answer (score 0):

Please change **MyHeight** property to **string** instead of **double** in **MyModel** class. I have faced similar issue before and solved it this way. Yes you have to do the unnecessary boxing and unboxing between string and double here.But this works.